# Eclipse console not terminating java class

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Java Console not terminating and new java project and class is not running]

Hi Guys, nothing is running and i think it's because of the console not terminating ( i keep trying to terminate or clear it and it doesn't work) a previous class/application even though i deleted it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: well from your console output vs the source code i'd say you have a mismatch on what program is actually getting run in eclipse

Comment: exactly and the program that it's running is no longer there. How do i tell it to stop running this mysterious code and run the one currently written?

Comment: The asterisk (*) next to the file name means that you haven't saved it...

Comment: I just saved it and it still hasn't worked.

Comment: Are you sure it's compiling ```classTest``` and not whatever the old class may have been?

Comment: I don't believe it's compiling classTest, i believe it's compiling a missing project/class. Soooo frustrating lol

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Eclipse specifically, but you should be able to go up to the menu bar and have it compile somewhere

Comment: Fixed it by restarting the Eclipse lol. Thank you all for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in your `classtest` editor window. Go down to `Run as` and select `Java Application`. That will compile your `classtest.java` and run it

Comment: Solved it by restarting the application. Thank you though